# esp8266 reading from envir current cost monitor seeing garbage characters on serial port (rpi reads without the unknown characters)

Tags: serial, esp8266

I'm trying to read the output of a current cost Envi-R monitor which outputs well spec'd xml over serial.  I have connected the Envi-R TX and GND to my esp8266 (a nodemcu dev board) and the xml can be seen, but it contains garbage characters.  The Envi-r outputs the message every 6 seconds or so,  and I see every message,  but every one is garbled in different locations as shown in the screenshot.

I hooked the Envi-R up to a raspberry pi using the same connections, and it reads the xml cleanly.

Both are set to the correct baud (57600).  I just can't work out why the esp is seeing the garbled characters.  The esp was programmed using the arduino ide.  I also tried micropython via Thonny but don't seem to able to read anything from the serial that way and failed to find any good examples.

I'd much rather just use a nodemcu if I can get a clean read of the xml (I'm just going to be forwarding it via mqtt for processing on a node-red install) so any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Cheers[image]

Comment: I guess it is because you read UART when there is no value. do you use Arduino read() function. it returns -1 if there is no byte to read.

Comment: So I'm using the softwareserial library, and am checking something is available before reading


`if (CC_SERIAL.available()) {...`

Comment: and then using `CC_SERIAL.readStringUntil('\n');`

Comment: is esp8266 SoftwareSerial capable to read at that baud rate?

Comment: yes from the documentation I believe it is.